# Куй [железо], пока тематика сайта ещё обсуждается

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Есть метка [железо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be). Есть темы — компьютерное железо, его сборка и починка, различные устройства и написание драйверов к ним, серверное оборудование...

Предлагаю обсудить и определиться: что из этого должно быть в тематике сайта, а что — нет. [Из справки:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>
> - к настройке физических, виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их настройки, мониторинга и этих автоматизации процессов;

Поскольку серверное администрирование входит в тематику, то очень хотелось бы услышать мнение профессионального системного администратора. Будет плохо, если мы разделим эту тему пополам и из двух тесно связанных вопросов один окажется по теме, а другой — нет.

Давайте обсуждать как на Area51 — предлагать примеры вопросов. Я совсем дилетант в этой области, поэтому почти наугад предлагаю вопрос, который лежит на границе настройки серверов и железа.

- Как правильно выбрать HDD для организации [RAID-массива](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID)?
- Как рассчитать требуемую конфигурацию сервера для базы данных? (Тут должна прилагаться схема).

Comment: До сих пор вопросы по железу, не связанные с программированием,  были оффтопиком и истреблялись.

Comment: @Nofate: однако эти вопросы есть на сайте и даже не все закрыты. Видимо, истреблялись недостаточно рьяно ) К тому же, я хотел бы иметь инструкцию для спорных случаев.

Comment: Я встретил сопротивление [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/344388/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) и [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/343194/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0). Даже не знаю, возможно отвеченные не стоит трогать?

Comment: @Cyrus: отвеченные стоит закрывать. Если на них есть заплюсованные ответы — никуда вопрос не денется, просто не будет в будущем собирать флуд вроде «ой, а у меня тоже сломался кулер». Конкретно этот вопрос является конкретным оффтопом: [Направление воздушного потока кулера?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/344388)

Comment: @Cyrus,  Qwertiy всегда против закрытия )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в текущую редакцию [онтопика](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) аппаратные проблемы не входят. Лично я против расширения тематики на железо, начнутся вопросы "какую выбрать видеокарту", а там недалеко и до "памагите жава не работает майнкрафт". Превратимся в гибрид Тостера и Ответы Мэйл.Ру.

Comment: @Nofate: не знаю, что хуже из этих двух сайтов. ) В целом я тоже против вопросов о железе, слишком они субъективны.

Comment: @Nofate Были упомянуты вопросы, которые не соответствовали бы идеи проекта даже, если бы речь в них шла про компиляторы, так как вопросы-опросники. Идея железа, на мой взгляд может обсуждаться в сообществе, если у нас есть (будут) настоящие знатоки. Если проецировать на программирование вопросы выбора железа, то они аналогичны «Много играю, хочу написать свою, что посоветуете для онлайн RPG java или php, слышал, что java тормозит». Настоящие вопросы по железу, как мне кажется, звучат в терминах «кольцевой топологии» и способах организации кластеров.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, если вопросы лежат в плоскости построения систем и организации IT-инфраструктуры - то ок, это в большей степени SF, чем железо. Если же вопросы будут про приклеивание кулера к процессору или "что-то блок питания барахлит", то это на мой взгляд не ок. Что вы думаете о двух примерах вопросов из поста Nick Volynkin (про raid и оценку сервера)?

Comment: @Nofate Первый, определенно, опросник. Если он поставлен в четкой форме, то я бы с радостью узнал как правильно работать с RAID-массивами. Второй, для меня, тоже выглядит интересным, но я лишь один из почти 30 тысяч участников. Подчеркну, на мой взгляд, вопросы не будут мусорными, а сайт помойкой, только в том случае, еси в сообществе будут знатоки тематики. Надеюсь именно они придут и выскажутся за или против.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: я там имел в виду не «какие HDD мне купить», а «каковы критерии выбора и чем руководствоваться при принятии решения».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: например, насколько я знаю, в массив никогда не ставят диски одной марки и производителя — велик шанс одновременной поломки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin имеется также прямо противоположное утверждение - необходимо собирать массивы (особенно) зеркала, из строго одинаковых дисков (из одной партии). Якобы в этом случае, латентность будет идентичной, а производительность - огромной. Зачастую эти рекомендации подкреплены одним - двумя очень частными примерами и выглядят, как карго-культ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin К сожалению, я не являюсь специалистом в этой области и судить не могу. В общем, должны соблюдаться те же правила, что и для программирования: избегать вопросов-опросников, всеобъемлющих вопросов и т. д, стараться задавать конкретные вопросы, на которые можно однозначно ответить. Но на сколько конкретный вопрос соответствует требованиям проекта, может судить лишь знаток. Против самой тематики «железа» лично я ничего не имею, наоборот, был бы только рад расширить профессиональный кругозор.

Comment: Тематика железа однозначно нужна. 1) Каждый с этим сталкивается, рано или поздно. 2) концепция ресурса очень удобна и ее расширение на железо и   администрирование неизбежно необходима.

Comment: @Raaur: администрирование уже входит в тематику. Что касается концепции — да, она действительно очень удобна. Но на поддержание порядка уходит много сил участников, а без этого порядка сайт утонет во флуде. Не так-то просто взять и расширить тематику на всё, что нам интересно. Нужны прежде всего заинтересованные и компетентные участники, которые будут отвечать на вопросы о железе и разгребать завалы.

Comment: "Qwertiy всегда против закрытия )" - не всегда, просто у меня своё мнение, что закрывать, а что нет. А ещё, если я жму "пропустить", то это ведь в логе не сохраняется?

Comment: @Qwertiy: нет, это точно не сохраняется.

Comment: @Raaur: предложил примерный список хороших и плохих вопросов. Предлагаю вам прочитать и высказать свое мнение.

Comment: Я за то, чтобы "железные" вопросы считались он-топиком. Вопрос про критерии, делающие HDD подходящими для RAID-массивов, хорош (и я попытаюсь на него ответить, т.к. это как раз по моей части). Вопрос про расчёт конфигурации плох, т.к., в лучшем случае, устаревает через пару-тройку лет (приходят новые поколения, а то и целые классы железок), в худшем - вообще одноразовый и, кроме автора, никому не интересен.

Comment: @AntonioK: был бы рад увидеть ответ на первый вопрос. Думаю, что он вполне будет в рамках темы системного администрирования. Как опубликуете — пинганите меня где-нибудь, я обязательно зайду прочитать.

Answer (score 8):

Пусть будет всё по теме.

Да и вообще, чем больше компьютерных и околокомпьютерных тем будут разрешены, тем лучше. Нет никакого смыла искусственно сужать тематику, когда, в отличие от английского SO, более конкретизированных русскоязычных сайтов сети нет.

Comment: Возможность топикастера на мете единогласно выбрать "правильный вариант" - это просто нечто :)

Comment: @PashaPash: прошло 4 дня и других вариантов ответа кроме «по теме» не было. Я это понял так, что почти всем вопрос безразличен, кроме Qwertiy и еще одного проголосовавшего.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я понимаю, просто сама по себе возможность  - очень сомнительная (в отрыве от этого конкретного вопроса)

Comment: @PashaPash: один из тех случаев, когда зеленая галочка означает «автор решил поставить на этот ответ зеленую галочку».

Answer (score 7):

Вопросы по администрированию и настройке северов - уже в списке онтопиков.

Предлагаю оставить чисто железные вопросы оффтопиком.

Основная проблема железных вопросов - проблему нельзя воспроизвести без наличия железа. Что сводит их к нескольким категориям:

- У меня <что-то> не работает, что делать? - В случае программирования требуется минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы. Что будем требовать в случае железа?
- Где найти инструкцию? - SO это сайт вопросов и ответов, а не каталог документации бесплатно без SMS.
- Какой конфиг выбрать для <чего-то>? - Если разработчик софта не проводил замеров и не выдал рекомендуемый или минимальный конфиг - то ответ на такой вопрос будет основан на мнении. Такие вопросы - оффтопик.

Comment: А всякие микроконтроллеры, ардуины, ПЛИС - оффтопик, али как?

Comment: @gbg разработка под них - онтопик. "подскажите разницу в пинах между малинкой А и малинкой B" - оффтопик.

Comment: то есть, если вопрос более софтовый - онтопик. А цепляние транзисторных ключей - офф?

Comment: @gbg примерно так. насчет ПЛИС я не уверен, но по опыту общения с одним разработчиком микросхем - у них там свой мир, свой специфический софт и свои специфические проблемы. они, конечно, интересные, но лично я не считаю их онтопиком. это скорее из категории пользования готовым софтом для решения железных проблем, чем разработки или администрирования.

Comment: там может (в редких случаях) быть интересная математика и алгоритмика. В целом, согласен.

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно. И так полно програмерского офтопика и тупняка. Ну а с этими темами, русский SO вообще превратится в клоаку, причём в обозримое время. Если цель такова - вы на верном пути.

Вот русский `Electronics` действительно нужен - и именно по электронике, а не на уровне "какой жесткий диск выбрать". К тому-же это вообще пост-опрос, что запрещено.

Тема поднималась, сообщество есть и достаточное количество заинтересованных людей готовы его раскручивать, но нет, удивительным образом тут поддерживается идея свалить всё в кучу. Как будто цель - лягушатник для русскоговорящих (*по недоразумению*) головастиков, а вовсе не улучшение качества контента, воспитание **русскоязычных специалистов** или помощь сообществам.

Comment: «Если цель такова - вы на верном пути.» — это вы к кому обращаетесь?

Comment: к тем членам сообщества, кто за сие направление, очевидно

Comment: "К тому-же это вообще пост-опрос, что запрещено." - вот именно, есть другие правила, по которым такие вопросы не пройдут, а хорошим - почему бы не быть?

Answer (score 1):

А какое собственно говоря железо? Вы его вообще где-то видели?

Все что у меня валяется в квартире до последнего транзистора в микроволновой печке - импорт. Расценки ребят из МЦСТ приводят в уныние. Да и что-то там обсуждать не имея всей документации и чертежей перед глазами это просто гиблое дело.

Не нужно. Скатится в идиотские вопросы типа:

1. Что лучше Intel или AMD?
2. Какой кулер купить чтобы эта хрень опять
   не сгорела?

Comment: Наконец-то к железной крепости подоспели осадные тролли. ))

Comment: @Nick Ну а как вы себе это представляете? Приходит парень, прикрепляет скриншот из электронного CAD и спрашивает: "Привет народ, что не так в схеме битового сдвига из АЛУ моего 48 ядерного процессора проекта SUPERVASYAPUPKIN_INTELFUCKER CORE i9 128bit?"

Comment: А в ответ я видимо должен с нуля, бесплатно начертить ему с закрытыми глазами за 5 минут, сидя на импортной икеевской кухне импортной ручкой на импортной бумаге новое отечественное квантовое АЛУ не имеющее аналогов в мире. Впрочем я уже давно привык к суровости этой страны и лучше перестану ныть в комментариях о том что все тлен и пойду сделаю что-нибудь полезное.

Comment: да, вот как-то так и представляю. И ещё единороги там должны пробегать.