# Не понимаю, за что мой вопрос закрыли?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Недавно задавал вопрос на ru.stackoverflow.com, я нашел в чем была причина моей проблемы, пометил свой вопрос как ответ и бац, после мой вопрос закрыли по причине "не по теме", в каком смысле? Тег у вопроса был "Железо", я и задал вопрос по этой теме! Вот вопрос: [Проблема с пятнами на экране!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002672/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5/1002682#1002682)

Comment: Просто вы задали вопрос на сайте, где тема (и метка сответственно) "железо" является второстепенной, главная тема - разработка ПО. Уже много раз обсуждалось, какие вопросы связанные с железом допускается здесь задавать. Точных критериев не было выработано, но примерно такое было предложено как отправная точка для оценки онтопичности вопросов по железу - "связанные с проффесиональной деятельностью, то онтопик". Ваша фраза - "раздражает, **в играх особенно**", дала, мне например,  повод пологать, что вопрос никак не связан с проффесиональной деятельностью и он не по теме.

Comment: Я привел пример того где оно проявляется, не только в браузере, но и в остальных приложениях, это показывает что проблема глобальна и не зависит от определенных приложений! (Так сказать, наводка на ответ в чем дело)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое иногда случается. Вопрос переоткрыл.

Comment: А на каком основании? Диагностику проблем с железом в тематику сайта никто не включал, кроме, возможно, серверного железа: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291/Куй-железо-пока-тематика-сайта-ещё-обсуждается

Comment: Весьма спорный кейс. У нас по соглашению принято про железо говорить только в контексте серверных железяк вроде как. А тут весьма неоднозначный кейс =/

Comment: @Suvitruf, думаю, хуже от вопроса никому не станет. Мало ли, может у кого такая же проблема возникнет…

Comment: @eanmos так а чем в этом плане закрытие мешает?

Comment: @Suvitruf, так закрытые вопросы удаляются же через некоторое время, разве нет?

Comment: @eanmos вроде как это зависит от количества голосов на них.

Comment: @eanmos закрытые вопросы с принятым или заплюсованным ответом не удаляются автоматически, но могут быть удалены голосованием (10К+ репы)

Comment: Открывая вопрос исходил из того, что не помню явного запрета на подобные вопросы + у нас тематика изначально шире чем у англо-саксонского аналога, т.к. мы меньше. А пост на мете из коммента выше - просто обсуждение, которым можно руководствоваться, но там явно не было конкретного и окончательного решения) Ну и сам вопрос (если включать в него и ответ), на мой взгляд, вполне нормален.