# Как бы нам установить, что такое [msi] и [msi]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

В данный момент, по метке [msi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msi) существует 21 вопрос.

Часть из них касается MSI (установочные пакеты)

- [Как внедрить установку Mssql в внутрь Msi расширения InstallerProjects?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1488300)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1455377
- [WIX Toolset внутри wine. torch.exe запускается с ошибкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461047)
- [Можно ли на линуксе собрать .msi пакет, который умеет после установки настраивать службу на windows(или умеет в пост скрипты)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452889)
- [Как запустить программу после установки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1448174)
- [Не устанавливается Node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1173490)
- ... и т.п.

Часть из них касается компании MSI (производитель "железа" и софта к нему).

- [Прыгает напряжение GPU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513158)
- [Как включить загрузку с NVME на MSI Z77A-G43?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144143)
- [При установке Win не видит hdd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795905)
- [Как программно управлять частотой и памятью на видеокарте как в MSI afterburner?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753389)
- [Как избавиться от ошибки PCIe bus error в Ubuntu 16.04.3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719653)

*Вопросы по "железу" у нас имеют неоднозначный статус (см. 2015 год -  [Куй [железо], пока тематика сайта ещё обсуждается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291)), однако **этот вопрос тут не поднимается**.*

Вопрос - как бы нам отделить метки инсталлятора MSI от компании MSI? Или может быть метка компании MSI нам вовсе не нужна, т.к. она не соответствует гайдлайнам, и надо просто снять её с вопросов, а к самой метке добавить описание, что она про инсталляторы?

Comment: Мне нравится вариант из последнего предложения.

Comment: *а к самой метке добавить описание, что она про инсталляторы?* Кабы его ещё кто-нибудь читал... можно заалиасить `msi` на `msi-пакет`, а для фирмы создать `msi-фирма`.

Comment: [tag:msi-фирма] - звучит как дичь ))

Comment: msi-package и msi-hardware?
Ну либо же msi-global, как вариант для железа.

Answer (score 7):

Вопросов ничтожно мало (21), по железной части - не превышает 25% (в абсолютном числе - 5 штук). Учитывая направленность ruSO в первую очередь на софте (т.е. мне кажется, если у активных участников спросить, что должна отражать метка [msi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msi) на сайте - ответ будет про софт, а не про компанию, производящую оборудование), предлагаю выпилить метку с вопросов по железу. И добавить в метку описание, что речь исключительно о [Windows Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer).

Comment: Так даже лучше, тем более, вспомним гайдлайны, нет ни одного вопроса, где бы метка msi-железо была бы единственной и описательной, вряд ли по метке может быть специалист.

Comment: Но тогда [msi] - мета-метка, у нас уже есть метка [windowsinstaller](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsinstaller)

Comment: @Зонтик почему "мета-метка"?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ потому что не может использоваться без другой метки. meet - встречаться, отсюда и мета.

Comment: @Зонтик вы не правы в терминологии. [msi] не мета-метка и вполне себе самостоятельна как [msi-пакет]. *"meet - встречаться, отсюда и мета"* - простите что??

Comment: @Зонтик а можно ссылку на такое определение "мета-метки"? Потому как я знаю о немного [другом.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/176217)

Comment: Кстати, верное замечание Зонтика - а не стоит ли тогда сделать msi синонимом к windowsinstaller вообще, или у них есть какое-то различие?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ оказывается я просто 
неправильно понимал термин "мета-метка"....

Comment: @Kromster синонимизация - это уже следующий этап, если будет принято решение что [msi] - это сугубо о инсталляторе. Но то что метка нашлась - безусловно хорошо.

Answer (score -3):

Коллективное предложение:

[msi-пакет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msi-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82) - для вопросов об MSI пакетах.

[msi-железо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msi-%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be) - для вопросов о железе (и прилагающемся к нему софте) от компании MSI.

Предлагайте другие варианты.